# Get data from Firebase (Real Time Database) Flutter using StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

First of all my Firebase structure looks like this:

[image: Firebase]

I want to get for example, CCV value and show it in my app GUI which looks like this:

[image: GUI]

All the card entries are structured in my code in a widget called `cardEntries()` and I think there I should build my `StreamBuilder` method, but I don't know a well structured method that can work.

Comment: The FlutterFire repo contain a full example, which I often copy bits from. See https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart#L147

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not quite useful, because its very complex and I dont fully understand the code there. Need something more precise.

Comment: Without seeing what you tried, it'll be hard to help better than any sample/docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to BloC pattern to implement Firebase Realtime Database on a StreamBuilder.

Create a model for your Card Info first. You can also include the json parser on the same class.

```dart
class CardInfo{
  String? cvv;
  String? cardHolder;
  String? number;
  String? expiry;
  CardInfo({this.cvv, this.cardHolder,
      this.number, this.expiry});

  factory CardInfo.fromJson({required Map<dynamic,dynamic> json}){
    return CardInfo(
      cvv: json['CVV'],
      cardHolder: json['Card Holder'],
      number: json['Credit Card Number'],
      expiry: json['Expiry Date'],
    );
  }
}
```

Add your Streams on a Bloc class

```dart
class Bloc {
  final _repository = Repository();
  final _cardInfoFetcher = StreamController<CardInfo>.broadcast();
  
  /// The Stream that will be used on StreamBuilder
  Stream<CardInfo> get userCardInfo => _cardInfoFetcher.stream;

  fetchUserThreads(String? userId) async {
    var cardInfo = CardInfo();

    /// Query user card details
    var userCardDetails = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users').child(userId)
      .child('Card Info');

    /// Fetch user card details once
    var snapshot = await userCardDetails.once();

    Map<dynamic, dynamic> userCardSnapshot = snapshot.value;
    _cardInfoFetcher.sink.add(CardInfo.fromJson(json: userCardSnapshot));
  }

  /// Dispose Stream when not in use
  dispose() {
    _cardInfoFetcher.close();
  }
}
final bloc = Bloc();
```

Every time `bloc.fetchUserThreads(String)` is called, StreamBuilder should do a widget rebuild.

```dart
StreamBuilder<CardInfo>(
  stream: bloc.userCardInfo,
  builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<CardInfo> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData)
      debugPrint('Snapshot empty');
    else {
      debugPrint('Card Holder: ${snapshot.data!.cardHolder}');
    }
    /// You can now populate child widget with CardInfo data from the snapshot
    return Container();
  }
)
```